# Auto fill a Custom Post Type title from ACF field

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I'd like to auto fill the title of three Custom Post Types (CPTs) based on an ACF field. I found the code below, but don't know how to write it for three CPTs instead of just one. I would appreciate the help!

```
function acf_title( $value, $post_id, $field ) {
    if ( get_post_type( $post_id ) == 'companies' ) {

        $new_title = get_field('company_name', $post_id) . ' ' . $value;
        $new_slug = sanitize_title( $new_title );

        wp_update_post( array(
            'ID'            => $post_id,
            'post_title'    => $new_title,
            'post_name'     => $new_slug,
            )
        );
    }
    return $value;
} 

add_filter('acf/update_value', 'acf_title', 10, 3);
```

Comment: One CPT is `companies` having custom field title `company_name`. What about the other CPTs name and their custom field title?

Comment: CPT's are contacts and properties with titles name_first and building_name

Comment: Check this. https://gist.github.com/logichub/e6347a12a69b156aada1a2147106ed96

Comment: @KashifRafique Yes! That worked for 2 of the 3! The only challenge here is that for contacts, it's a group field with first and last name. The title returns "ARRAY". Any ideas? I google the crap out of this, and it seems like a common question. Basically, it needs to have two fields in the title individually: First and Last Name

Comment: Can you share the screenshot of this group field? What I got from your above comment is that **Contact** group field contains 2 sub-fields namely `first_name` and `last_name`? You can retrieve the sub-fields value by using `get_sub_field()` function. Check the docs at https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/group/. See the last example.

Comment: @KashifRafique I got it working! Thanks again for your help. The very sticky problem is to update a taxonomy (status) from a custom field (status) upon publish or update. How would I tweak the code to do this? Also, I'd like to send you a few bucks for your help and (if you're freelancing) help me on future projects. Let me know if you're up for it!

Comment: I have posted the gist as an answer so you can upvote/accept it here. Thanks for your compliment. Yes, I do freelance work and happy to assist you. Let's connect on Linkedin.

Comment: < *The very sticky problem is to update a taxonomy (status) from a custom field (status) upon publish or update. How would I tweak the code to do this?* > Can you share more detail with the code / screenshot(s) in a separate question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code. It should work for you.

```
<?php
// Auto fill Title and Slug for 'companies' CPT
function acf_title_companies( $value, $post_id, $field ) {
    if ( get_post_type( $post_id ) == 'companies' ) {
        $new_title = get_field( 'company_name', $post_id ) . ' ' . $value;
        $new_slug = sanitize_title( $new_title );
        wp_update_post( array(
            'ID'         => $post_id,
            'post_title' => $new_title,
            'post_name'  => $new_slug,
            )
        );
    }
    return $value;
} 
add_filter( 'acf/update_value/name=company_name', 'acf_title_companies', 10, 3 );
// Auto fill Title and Slug for 'contacts' CPT
function acf_title_contacts( $value, $post_id, $field ) {
    if ( get_post_type( $post_id ) == 'contacts') {
        $new_title = get_field( 'name_first', $post_id ) . ' ' . $value;
        $new_slug = sanitize_title( $new_title );
        wp_update_post( array(
            'ID'         => $post_id,
            'post_title' => $new_title,
            'post_name'  => $new_slug,
            )
        );
    }
    return $value;
} 
add_filter( 'acf/update_value/name=name_first', 'acf_title_contacts', 10, 3 );
// Auto fill Title and Slug for 'properties' CPT
function acf_title_properties( $value, $post_id, $field ) {
    if ( get_post_type( $post_id ) == 'properties') {
        $new_title = get_field( 'building_name', $post_id ) . ' ' . $value;
        $new_slug = sanitize_title( $new_title );
        wp_update_post( array(
            'ID'         => $post_id,
            'post_title' => $new_title,
            'post_name'  => $new_slug,
            )
        );
    }
    return $value;
} 
add_filter( 'acf/update_value/name=building_name', 'acf_title_properties', 10, 3 );
```

---

### Update

Replace the previous code with the following. It will resolve the double title issue as noted by [Andrew](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8287392/andrew) in below comment.

```
<?php

// Auto fill Title and Slug for CPT's - 'companies', 'contacts', 'properties'
function lh_acf_save_post( $post_id ) {

    // Don't do this on the ACF post type
    if ( get_post_type( $post_id ) == 'acf' ) {
        return;
    }

    $new_title = '';
    $new_slug = '';

    // Get title from 'companies' CPT acf field 'company_name'
    if ( get_post_type( $post_id ) == 'companies' ) {
        $new_title = get_field( 'company_name', $post_id );
        $new_slug = sanitize_title( $new_title );
    }

    // Get title from 'contacts'CPT acf field 'contact_name'
    if ( get_post_type( $post_id ) == 'contacts') {
        $contact_name = get_field( "contact_name" );
        if ( $contact_name ) {
            $name_first = $contact_name['name_first'];
            $name_last = $contact_name['name_last'];
        }
        $new_title = $name_first . ' ' . $name_last;
        $new_slug = sanitize_title( $new_title );
    }

    // Get title from 'properties' CPT acf field 'building_name'
    if ( get_post_type( $post_id ) == 'properties') {
        $new_title = get_field( 'building_name', $post_id );
        $new_slug = sanitize_title( $new_title );
    }

    // Prevent iInfinite looping...
    remove_action( 'acf/save_post', 'lh_acf_save_post' );

    // Grab post data
    $post = array(
        'ID'            => $post_id,
        'post_title'    => $new_title,
        'post_name'     => $new_slug,
    );

    // Update the Post
    wp_update_post( $post );

    // Continue save action
    add_action( 'acf/save_post', 'lh_save_post' );

    // Set the return URL in case of 'new' post
    $_POST['return'] = add_query_arg( 'updated', 'true', get_permalink( $post_id ) );
}
add_action( 'acf/save_post', 'lh_acf_save_post', 10, 1 );
```

Tested and working on:

1. WordPress 5.0.3
2. Twentyninteen 1.2
3. Advanced Custom Fields PRO 5.7.10
4. Localhost (XAMPP for Windows 5.6.15)

Comment: I noticed an issue with this. When I update the title, it seems to add the title twice (in the title and slug). Here's a screencast of what I'm talking about it. https://drive.google.com/file/d/1zIo5ywxfx1wg_lSfyqUmmSnClEW8RdES/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @Andrew see the updated answer. I have added a new code that will resolve the subject issue.

Comment: THANK YOU. Tested and works! How can I ping you for future stuff?

Comment: Welcome! Glad to be helpful here. Let's connect on [LinkedIn](https://www.linkedin.com/in/rafiquekashif/).